# How to get the current state of saved post in recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have an app where users posts photos and can save the post, then view it later.

OnClick of save image, the image changes and records are inserted into the database, and OnClick again, the image changes to the unsaved state and the records are deleted in the database.

The Problem - When I exit the app and return to thesame Activity, the state of the saved Image is lost.

I have 2 database tables - 'images' and 'saved_images'.

The uploaded images(url), uploader(uid), are saved in the 'images' table after upload.

While the person who saved the image (uid), the saved_image(id) are saved in the 'saved_images' table after clicking save.

**Content.xml** - Has the save image View

```
 <ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/savePhotoIcon"
   android:src="@drawable/outline_bookmark_border_black_48dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 />
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.save_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Boolean saved = true;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(saved){
                holder.save_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.outline_bookmark1_black_48dp);
                saved = false;
                saveToDatabase(position);
            }
            else{
                saved = true;
                holder.save_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.outline_bookmark_border_black_48dp);
                removeFromDatabase(position);
            }
        }
    });

 }
```

I am supposed to do a check between the current logged in user and the image been displayed in the recycler view. That is - If the current user has saved a particular post {show the unsave image} else{show the save image} but I dont know how to wrap my head around doing this.

NB - I can get the id of the current logged in user and also the id of the image shown.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you have a boolean called `saved` which you simply set to true in the beginning and which will never persist, so if you close the app and then reopen it it will be forgotten. Hell, it will even be forgotten if you just scroll away from your position in the recyclerview for too long.

the solution is to save the `saved` boolean variable in your database next to the uid of your user. that way instead of just declaring `saved=true` in onBindViewHolder you can do `saved=yourUidList.get(position).getIsSaved();` and get the info about whether uid should be true or false.

Alternatively, you can have a method that you execute in onBindViewHolder that basically loops through your saved_Images table and returns a boolean that is true whenever that users uid matches up with some substring in the saved_images url. but this approach is rather inefficient and i dont recommend it.